# Can I add navigation arrows to PDF output in SSRS / Report Builder 3.0?

Tags: ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

Somebody pulled the most random question on me today and I realized I'd never even considered it. What they wanted was my PDF rendering of an SSRS report to come standard with navigation arrows, i.e., previous page, next page. This started me looking at all the options that are available, which are actually kind of cool, and I was able to add on a table of contents, including bookmarks for a new number (e.g., if you're printing 5 invoices with 2-5 pages each into one long document, those will have the invoice number and you can jump to the beginning of that invoice), but I couldn't see anything about navigation links. In fact, most of what I've seen says that PDF's only can have navigation maps, i.e., the table of contents tab. So if anyone has any ideas on how I can do this, that would be great. I know it can be added after-the-fact with something like Blubeam, but that's not practical in this case.

Comment: You can include bookmarks to (almost) every item in your report, so when the report is exported to PDF it creates a link to each item in the bookmark menu. Let me know if that is what you are after

Comment: That's good to know, thanks. Is there a way to make them dynamic, e.g., have a bookmark on each page that jumps to the previous / next page?

Comment: That's not possible but you can create a bookmark on each page, you just need to name it like page 1, page 2,... to let the user can jump to the page he/she wants to using the bookmark menu. Let me know If that sounds like a possible solution I'll post it.

Comment: Sure, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments you can create a bookmark in each page. A bookmark can be added using the component `DocumentMapLabel` property almost all SSRS Report Items (Tablix, Textbox, Charts, etc) have.

If you don't have a title or a textbox at the very top of each page, add an empty textbox, be sure place them at the top of the page in order to each bookmark jumps to the beginning of the corresponding page.

Select the first textbox and press `F4` to see the extended properties window, look for `DocumentMapLabel` and type `Page 1`.

[image][image]

In each page set the textbox DocumentMapLabel property to the corresponding page number.

When the report is exported to PDF, your PDF client shows the bookmark menu, containing a bookmark for each page. If you click on a bookmark it jumps to the related page.

This is how it looks in Adobe Acrobar Reader:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This is extremely useful. Thanks. What happens when it wraps onto a new page?

Comment: @DaveX, If you mean it expands to the next page, the bookmark will jump to the first page where the item is placed, so you have to be careful while placing the items used to reference each page and setting the page breaks.